# \caption full features, but no showing at list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

Using tocloft for my list of figures, I am looking for some method that enables me to select some specific entires (\caption) such as that one further down, which shouldn't goes to the list of figures, but in the content still be counted/numbered in the usual way.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{rhythmus.pdf}
\caption[Own grafic.]{Beispielrhythmus: Ta ta tatata, tata tataa ta taa.}
\label{rhythmus}
\end{figure}
```

I use the list of figure to show the sources of the figures, but I have many selfmade grafics, where I don't need to specify the source. Respectively I will specifiy them just with one sentence.

I have following settings in the preamble, which might play a role.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 % This is for using numbering for the sections, chapters, etc. in the content, but not in the table of content.
\makeatletter
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\numberline}{\oldnumberline}{}{} %
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

Then:

```
\chapter{List of Figures}
{\makeatletter
%\let\@cftmakeloftitle\relax
\@starttoc{lof}% Print List of Figures
%\listoffigures
\makeatother}
\begingroup\noindent \footnotesize{Abb. 1.1, 1.2 ... here some more.. are made by myself}\endgroup
```

Comment: Do you want that *nothing* goes to the list of figures for that particular figure? I'm asking why. Or do you want that no numbering appears in the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "erasing some entries in the list of figures"? Do you want to prevent them from showing up entirely, or do you want them to show up as unnumbered entries?

Comment: The edit made the question even less clear.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now?

Comment: I still can't understand why you want this. However, saying `\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}` in the body of the `figure` environment does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing

```
\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{rhythmus.pdf}
\caption[Own grafic.]{Beispielrhythmus: Ta ta tatata, tata tataa ta taa.}
\label{rhythmus}
\end{figure}
```

will neutralize the writing of anything in the `.lof` file. The effect of the `\renewcommand` will disappear at the end of the environment. Of course the optional argument to `\caption` serves no purpose, in this case.

Comment: If the `caption` package is loaded (anyway) one could also use `\caption[]{Beispielrhythmus: ...}` instead of redefining `\addcontentsline`. This will suppress the LOF entry, too.